# Trying to write an embedded sql in php. can't figure out this syntax error

Tags: php, sql

I've been sitting for some time behind the screen trying to fix this code. whenever i run it i get a syntax error indicating to the last line of the code. What i'm trying to do is write a web based database where i can add, update, delete, and retrieve information from the database.

```
<head>
    <title></title>

<script src="prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<?= $_POST["type"];?>
<?php $sel=$_POST["select"];?>
<?php if($_POST["type"]=="fm"){

    if($sel=="addnew"){

    try {
                $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=university", "root", "");
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $rows=$db->query("INSERT INTO fminformationtable 
                VALUES('$_POST[iden]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[fname]','$_POST[office]','$_POST[ext]','$_POST[hphone]','$_POST[mobile]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[syear]','$_POST[tyear]','$_POST[ldegree]','$_POST[ofrom]','$_POST[dyear]','$_POST[rinterest]')");

            }
            catch (PDOException $ex) {
            ?>
        <p>Sorry there was an Error in Adding</p>
            <?php
            }
            if($sel=="update"){


                try {
                    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=university", "root", "");
                    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



                    $rows=$db->query("UPDATE fminformationtable SET
                     Office=`$_POST[office]`,
                     Extension=`$_POST[ext]`,
                     HomePhone=`$_POST[hphone]',
                     MobilePhone=`$_POST[mobile]`,
                     Adress=`$_POST[address]`,
                     Email=`$_POST[email]`,
                     StartingYear=`$_POST[syear]`,
                     TerminationYrear=`$_POST[tyear]`,
                     LatestDegree=`$_POST[ldegree]`,
                     ObtainedFrom=`$_POST[ofrome]`,
                     DegreeYear=`$_POST[dyear]`,
                     ResearchInterest=`$_POST[rinterest]`

                    ");

                    }


                catch (PDOException $ex) {


                }
        }
         if($sel=="delete"){
            try {
                    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=university", "root", "");
                    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    $rows = $db->exec("DELETE FROM fminformationtable WHERE FM_ID = '$_POST[iden]'"); 


            }
            catch (PDOException $ex) {

                }
        }

        if($sel=="getinfo"){
                    try {
                    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=university", "root", "");
                    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    $rows = $db->exec("SEEELECT * FROM fminformationtable WHERE FM_ID = '$_POST[iden]'"); 

                    }


            catch (PDOException $ex) {

                }

        }

    }
}
if($_POST["type"]=="ct"){
    if($sel=="addnew"){

    try {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=university", "root", "");
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $rows=$db->query("INSERT INTO coursetable 
                VALUES('$_POST[cnum]','$_POST[ctitle]','$_POST[credits]','$_POST[semester]','$_POST[type]','$_POST[desc]','$_POST[outcomes]')");



    }
        catch (PDOException $ex) {

                }
}

                    if($sel=="update"){


                try {
                    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=university", "root", "");
                    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



                    $rows=$db->query("UPDATE coursetable SET
                    CourseNumber=`$_POST[cnum]`,
                    CourseTitle=`$_POST[ctitle]`,
                    CreditNumb=`$_POST[credits]`,
                    SemesterOffered=`$_POST[semester]`,
                    CourseType=`$_POST[ctype]`,
                    CourseDescription=`$_POST[desc]`,
                    LearningOut=`$_POST[outcomes]`
                    ");


            }
            catch (PDOException $ex) {

                }
        }

         if($sel=="delete"){
            try {
                    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=university", "root", "");
                    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    $rows = $db->exec("DELETE FROM coursetable WHERE CourseNumber = '$_POST[cnum]'"); 


            }
            catch (PDOException $ex) {

                }

            }

                if($sel=="getinfo"){
                    try {
                    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=university", "root", "");
                    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    $rows = $db->exec("SEEELECT * FROM coursetable WHERE CourseNumber = '$_POST[cnum]'"); 

                    }


            catch (PDOException $ex) {
                }
        }


            }

            if($_POST["type"]=="ch"){

                if($sel=="addnew"){


                try {
                    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=university", "root", "");
                    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    $rows=$db->query("INSERT INTO coursehistory 
                VALUES('$_POST[cnum]','$_POST[year]','$_POST[semester]','$_POST[sec]','$_POST[inID]','$_POST[comments]' )");            
            }
                catch (PDOException $ex) {
                }
            if($sel=="update"){

                try {
                    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=university", "root", "");
                    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    $rows=$db->query("UPDATE coursetable SET
                    AcademicYear=`$_POST[year]`,
                    Semester=`$_POST[semester]`,
                    InstructorID=`$_POST[inID]`,
                    Section=`$_POST[sec]`,
                    Comments=`$_POST[comments]`
                    WHERE CourseNumber=`$_POST[cnum]`;");


                    }
                    catch (PDOException $ex) {

                }


            }
            if($sel=="delete"){
            try {
                    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=university", "root", "");
                    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    $rows = $db->exec("DELETE FROM coursehistory WHERE CourseNumber = '$_POST[cnum]'"); 


            }
            catch (PDOException $ex) {

                }

            }
                if($_POST["type"]=="gs"){
                    if($sel=="addnew"){

                        try {
                        $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=university", "root", "");
                        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                        $rows=$db->query("INSERT INTO gradtable 
                        VALUES('$_POST[fmid]','$_POST[sid]','$_POST[sname]','$_POST[dyear]','$_POST[dsemester]','$_POST[status]','$_POST[option]','$_POST[title]','$_POST[mandyear]'        
                        )");
                }
                catch (PDOException $ex) {

                }

                if($sel=="delete"){
            try {
                    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=university", "root", "");
                    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    $rows = $db->exec("DELETE FROM gradtable WHERE StudentId = '$_POST[sid]'"); 


            }
            catch (PDOException $ex) {

                }

            }
                if($sel=="update"){


                try {
                    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=university", "root", "");
                    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



                    $rows=$db->query("UPDATE gradtable SET
                    FMID=`$_POST[fmid]`,
                    StudentID=`$_POST[sid]`,
                    StudentName=`$_POST[sname]`,
                    DegreeStart=`$_POST[dyear]`,
                    DegreeSemester=`$_POST[dsemester]`,
                    Status=`$_POST[status]`,
                    Option=`$_POST[option]`,
                    Title=`$_POST[title]`,
                    Month_Year=`$_POST[mandyear]`
                    ");


            }
            catch (PDOException $ex) {

                }


?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting ... ?

Comment: *Usually* if you get an error referencing the last line, you are missing a closing character. This could be a curly brace `}`, square bracket `]`, parenthesis `)` or quote (double or single). This isn't the whole list, but a large chunk.

Answer (score 3):

Your `if($sel=="update"){` might be missing a closing brace.

EDIT: Actually, looking at your code further, it seems that you are missing quite a few closing braces.
I suggest you take 5 minutes away from the monitor to clear your head, come back and you'll see them all jump out at you.

Comment: I concur. Properly indent your code and you will be able to see the issues better.

Comment: What's the error, exactly?
And please post your new code, including the added braces, so that we can correctly identify line 95.